# how to control formatting for google doc html upload

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I am uploading an html doc which has embedded `<style>` for p element. This seems to control p elements at the top level, but not if they're in a list.

Here's an excerpt of the html being used to upload the file, with deleted content shown with ":"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
p, li {
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Status Report Summary: Board Meeting Demo - 2020-10-12</h2>

:

    <h3>Market Street Mile - Lou King</h3>
    <p>Here's my status for Market Street Mile</p>
    
        <p><b>For discussion:</b></p>
        <ul class="statusreport">
            
                <li><p>Market Street Mile registrations are low</p><p>the market street mile has been suffering</p><ul><li>this is one reason</li><li>this is another reason</li></ul></li>
            
                <li><p>sponsorships are up</p><p>sponsorship details</p></li>
            
        </ul>
    
:

</body>
```

This is formatted in the file as follows

[image: google doc formatting result]

As you can see the p element formatting works for "Here's my status for Market Street Mile", but not after "Market Street Mile registrations are low. (Also note li element formatting not working).

Is there some documentation somewhere on what can and cannot be formatted with css for google doc html upload, or description of how to get the desired formatting?

I'm using google doc api, but I expect the same would be true on native upload of html with conversion.

UPDATE 10/5/20:

For reference, here is the code which creates the file. Not sure this is relevant, though.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

class GoogleAuthService():
    """
    methods to interact with google api using service based credentials (e.g., for server authentication)

    * see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

    :param service_account_file: service_account_file.json path
    :param scopes: list of google scopes. see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
    :param logdebug: (optional) debug logger function
    :param logerror: (optional) debug logger function
    """

    def __init__(self, service_account_file, scopes, loginfo=None, logdebug=None, logerror=None):
        self.service_account_file = service_account_file
        self.scopes = scopes
        self.loginfo = loginfo
        self.logdebug = logdebug
        self.logerror = logerror
        self.credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(self.service_account_file, scopes=self.scopes)
        self.drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=self.credentials)

    def create_file(self, folderid, filename, contents, doctype='html'):
        """
        create file in drive folder

        ..note::
            folderid must be shared read/write with services account email address

        :param folderid: drive id for folder file needs to reside in
        :param filename: name for file on drive
        :param contents: path for file contents (docx formatted)
        :param doctype: 'html' or 'docx', default 'html'
        :return: google drive id for created file
        """
        ## upload (adapted from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
        file_metadata = {
            'name': filename,
            # see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
            # see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder
            'parents': [folderid],
        }

        # mimetype depends on doctype
        mimetype = _getmimetype(doctype)

        # create file
        media = MediaFileUpload(
            contents,
            mimetype=mimetype,
            resumable=True
        )
        file = self.drive.files().create(
            body=file_metadata,
            media_body=media,
            fields='id'
        ).execute()
        fileid = file.get('id')
        return fileid

def _getmimetype(doctype):
    """
    determine mimetype for specified doctype
    :param doctype: 'html' or 'docx'
    :return: mimetype
    """
    if doctype not in ['docx', 'html']:
        raise parameterError('_getmimetype(): doctype must be "docx" or "html", found {}'.format(doctype))

    if doctype == 'docx':
        mimetype = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    else:  # html
        mimetype = 'text/html'

    return mimetype
```

Comment: Could you please provide information on how are you uploading the document (including related code), and how are you accessing and viewing it?

Comment: @lamblichus I've added the code which uploads the document, although not sure if it will be relevant. I am accessing the document the normal way, through the g suite browser interface.

Comment: BTW, the same behavior can be seen if the html snippet is put into a file and uploaded directly to google drive, allowing conversion.

Comment: Also cross posted to https://support.google.com/docs/thread/75074048?hl=en, will answer here if something useful comes back there